# Is PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor of any use at all?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, entitymanager, spring-data

According to its JavaDoc, PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor seems to be responsible for injecting the EntityManager with the annotation @PersistenceContext. It appears to imply without this bean declared in the Spring application context xml, the @PersistenceContext annotation won't work.

However, based on my experiments, this is not the truth.

### Persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
</persistence>
```

### Spring application context XML

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.dao" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/c:\derbydb\mydb"/>
    <property name="username" value="APP"/>
    <property name="password" value="APP"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- 
    <bean id="persistenceAnnotation" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
 -->
```

### UserDaoImpl

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) {
            entityManager.persist(user);
    }
}
```

Whether I comment or uncomment the persistenceAnnotation bean, the result is the same. It doesn't hurt to leave the bean around, but what's the use of this bean?

I am using Spring 3.0.5.

Could someone provide a scenario where taking out this bean will result in failure?

Also I am not fond of creating an empty persistence unit just to fool Spring. Luckily this problem has been addressed in Spring 3.1.0.

Comment: I am guessing the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` implicitly includes the `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` so the explicit declaration is not needed.

Comment: Interesting point. I thought <tx:annotation-driven/> was related to the Transactional annotation. But you could be right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` transparently activated by the `<context:component-scan />` element. To be precise it's the `<context:annotation-config />` element that activates the bean but this element in turn gets transparently activated by `<context:component-scan />`.

Answer (score 7):

As Oliver Gierke mentioned, `org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is automatically loaded into App Context by Spring when using annotation based configuration. One of its duties is to search the proper entity `EntityManagerFactory` that would provide the `EntityManager` for you `@PersistenceContext` annotated properties.

If you have multiple `EntityManagerFactory` beans in you spring config/context and you have `@PersistenceContext` annotations without a `unitName` attribute (lets say you are using a framework that comes with such a bean, and you can't touch framework code), you may run into this exception: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`.

I found this workaround in case you tun into this:

```
<bean id="org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" >
<property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

This would override the default `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` loaded by Spring with a new one with `defaultPersistenceUnitName`.

Comment: Thanks ! After hours of research, this unblocked the situation for me. Sadly, I can't understand why setting primary on the default EntityManagerFactory is not supported here :(. It would be really more intuitive. (still the solution for Spring 4)